# Capture Output and Errors of Goroutine Using Channels

Tags: go, error-handling, concurrency

I have a for-loop that calls a function `runCommand()` which runs a remote command on a switch and prints the output. The function is called in a goroutine on each iteration and I am using a `sync.Waitgroup` to synchronize the goroutines. Now, I need a way to capture the output and any errors of my `runCommand()` function into a channel. I have read many articles and watched a lot of videos on using channels with goroutines, but this is the first time I have ever written a concurrent application and I can't seem to wrap my head around the idea.

Basically, my program takes in a list of hostnames from the command line then asynchronously connects to each host, runs a configuration command on it, and prints the output. It is ok for my program to continue configuring the remaining hosts if one has an error.

How would I idiomatically send the output or error(s) of each call to `runCommand()` to a channel then receive the output or error(s) for printing?

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "os"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    hosts := os.Args[1:]
    clientConf := configureClient("user", "password")

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, host := range hosts {
        wg.Add(1)
        go runCommand(host, &clientConf, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("Configuration complete!")
}

// Run a remote command
func runCommand(host string, config *ssh.ClientConfig, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // Connect to the client
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", host+":22", config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer client.Close()
    // Create a session
    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer session.Close()
    // Get the session output
    output, err := session.Output("show lldp ne")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Print(string(output))
    fmt.Printf("Connection to %s closed.\n", host)
}

// Set up client configuration
func configureClient(user, password string) ssh.ClientConfig {
    var sshConf ssh.Config
    sshConf.SetDefaults()
    // Append supported ciphers
    sshConf.Ciphers = append(sshConf.Ciphers, "aes128-cbc", "aes256-cbc", "3des-cbc", "des-cbc", "aes192-cbc")
    // Create client config
    clientConf := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        Config:          sshConf,
        User:            user,
        Auth:            []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password(password)},
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        Timeout:         time.Second * 5,
    }
    return *clientConf
}
```

**EDIT:** I got rid of the Waitgroup, as suggested, and now I need to keep track of which output belongs to which host by printing the hostname before printing its output and printing a `Connection to <host> closed.` message when the gorouttine completes. For example:

```
$ go run main.go host1[,host2[,...]]
Connecting to <host1>
[Output]
...
[Error]
Connection to <host1> closed.

Connecting to <host2>
...
Connection to <host2> closed.

Configuration complete!
```

I know the above won't necessarily process `host1` and `host2` in order, But I need to print the correct host value for the connecting and closing messages before and after the output/error(s), respectively. I tried defering printing the closing message in the `runCommand()` function, but the message is printed out before the output/error(s). And printing the closing message in the for-loop after each goroutine call doesn't work as expected either.

Updated code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type CmdResult struct {
    Host string
    Output string
    Err error
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    hosts := os.Args[1:]
    clientConf := configureClient("user", "password")
    results := make(chan CmdResult)

    for _, host := range hosts {
        go runCommand(host, &clientConf, results)
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(hosts); i++ {
        output := <- results
        fmt.Println(output.Host)
        if output.Output != "" {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", output.Output)
        }
        if output.Err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", output.Err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Configuration complete! [%s]\n", time.Since(start).String())
}

// Run a remote command
func runCommand(host string, config *ssh.ClientConfig, ch chan CmdResult) {
    // This is printing before the output/error(s).
    // Does the same when moved to the bottom of this function.
    defer fmt.Printf("Connection to %s closed.\n", host)

    // Connect to the client
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", host+":22", config)
    if err != nil {
        ch <- CmdResult{host, "", err}
        return
    }
    defer client.Close()
    // Create a session
    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        ch <- CmdResult{host, "", err}
        return
    }
    defer session.Close()
    // Get the session output
    output, err := session.Output("show lldp ne")
    if err != nil {
        ch <- CmdResult{host, "", err}
        return
    }
    ch <- CmdResult{host, string(output), nil}
}

// Set up client configuration
func configureClient(user, password string) ssh.ClientConfig {
    var sshConf ssh.Config
    sshConf.SetDefaults()
    // Append supported ciphers
    sshConf.Ciphers = append(sshConf.Ciphers, "aes128-cbc", "aes256-cbc", "3des-cbc", "des-cbc", "aes192-cbc")
    // Create client config
    clientConf := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        Config:          sshConf,
        User:            user,
        Auth:            []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password(password)},
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        Timeout:         time.Second * 5,
    }
    return *clientConf
}
```

Comment: So what's your goal here?  Are you trying to get very accurate display of the order things happen via printing to stdout?  Are you trying to get nicely formatted output that ignores the fact that concurrency doesn't guarantee the order of events across different goroutines without setting up some sort of scheduling scheme?  Depending on what you want, you may not need channels at all, you could just print to stdout from the goroutine and go back to using a waitgroup so you can print your final message from main after all runCommands complete.

Comment: @jrefior The ladder: getting nicely formatted output that ignores the order of events.

Comment: And what order are you looking for?  The original order of the hosts list?  Alphabetical by host name?  Something else?

Comment: @jrefior Basically, just need to match the correct hostname with its output/error, regardless of the order the hosts are processed. So if `host3` is processed first, `host7` second, etc., I want to print the hostname followed by its output/error followed by a closing message including the hostname. If you look at the flow of `runCommand`, I want to print the hostname before `ssh.Dial()` and print `Connection to <hostname> closed` after sending `session.Output()` to `ch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an unbuffered channel, you actually don't need the `sync.WaitGroup`, because you can call the receive operator on the channel once for every goroutine that will send on the channel.  Each receive operation will block until a send statement is ready, resulting in the same behavior as a WaitGroup.

To make this happen, change runCommand to execute a send statement exactly once before the function exits, under all conditions.

First, create a type to send over the channel:

```
type CommandResult struct {
    Output      string
    Err         error
}
```

And edit your `main() {...}` to execute a receive operation on the channel the same number of times as the number of goroutines that will send to the channel:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan CommandResult) // initialize an unbuffered channel
    // rest of your setup
    for _, host := range hosts {
        go runCommand(host, &clientConf, ch) // pass in the channel
    }
    for x := 0; x < len(hosts); x++ {
        fmt.Println(<-ch) // this will block until one is ready to send
    }
```

And edit your runCommand function to accept the channel, remove references to WaitGroup, and execute the send exactly once under all conditions:

```
func runCommand(host string, config *ssh.ClientConfig, ch chan CommandResult) {
    // do stuff that generates output, err; then when ready to exit function:
    ch <- CommandResult{output, err}
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Question updated with stdout message order requirements

> I'd like to get nicely formatted output that ignores the order of events

In this case, remove all print messages from runCommand, you're going to put all output into the element you're passing on the channel so it can be grouped together.  Edit the `CommandResult` type to contain additional fields you want to organize, such as:

```
type CommandResult struct {
    Host        string
    Output      string
    Err         error
}
```

If you don't need to sort your results, you can just move on to printing the data received, e.g.

```
for x := 0; x < len(hosts); x++ {
    r := <-ch
    fmt.Printf("Host: %s----\nOutput: %s\n", r.Host, r.Output)
    if r.Err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %s\n", r.Err)
    }
}
```

If you do need to sort your results, then in your `main` goroutine, add the elements received on the channel to a slice:

```
    ...
    results := make([]CommandResult, 0, len(hosts))
    for x := 0; x < len(hosts); x++ {
        results = append(results, <-ch) // this will block until one is ready to send
    }
```

Then you can use [the `sort` package](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) in the Go standard library to sort your results for printing.  For example, you could sort them alphabetically by host.  Or you could put the results into a map with host string as the key instead of a slice to allow you to print in the order of the original host list.

Comment: So if there is an error during, say, creating the session, i would put `ch <- CommandResult{“”, err}` and a return statement in the `if err != nil {}` block?

Comment: Also, when/where would I close the channel? Does it need to be closed explicitly in this case?

Comment: No the channel does not need to be closed in this case.  A close is typically intended as a flag to indicate that no more sends will occur on a buffered channel (though it can be used in other ways as well).  In particular, it stops `for e := range ch {...}` loops from being infinite loops.

Comment: @mwalto7 you could either add a send to each block containing a return, or you could take out the returns and use if-else and just send at the end with the values of output and err. It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks! I added my updated code implementing your suggestions above. Having trouble printing things in order, though.

Comment: @mwalto7 With the mulltiple runCommand goroutines, you're doing concurrent processing without any guarantee as to which runCommand will be ready to send first, second, ..., last.  Where does your desired order come from?  You might consider adding an ordinal int to `CommandResult`, putting the received values into a slice, and then sorting them.  Or maybe you have some other sort criteria?  Try to figure it out, and if you can't, then you could post it as a new question....Ah, I see your edit now, I'll take a closer look.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Got it working as expected.